# Fastest/easiest way to install Ubuntu on Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, wubi

I'm sorry if this is asked frequently but I have a problem, the computer I'm going to install Ubuntu is not mine and can only keep it for about 4-5 days, however I need Linux for homework.

In the past I used wubi so it was easy enough but everything I've read for a while says is no longer an option.

It's been 4 years or so since I last installed anything Linux related, I use Ubuntu on my PC but that was long ago, and I'm reading stuff like this:

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/07/how-to-install-linux-mint-alongside.html

http://linux.about.com/od/LinuxNewbieDesktopGuide/ss/The-Ultimate-Windows-81-And-Ubuntu-Dual-Boot-Guide.htm

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

That, to someone that messes up installations as good as I, it seems just too complicated, and I don't want to mess someone else's computer.

So, the question: *How to install a minimum version so I can compile and run C programs I write?*

Comment: You should use a VM, then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: I'd suggest you  install [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) in Windows then install a light weight Linux such as [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) in the virtual machine. You will have slightly reduced linux performance but not enough to notice it and almost no chance of upseting Windows.

Comment: In the past I tried to install a VM (last time this happened) and the computer froze so much I couldn't do anything. It's a laptop, not THAT bad but still, the VM did not work. That's only part of what I was talking when I say I mess stuff up

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You dont need to install Ubuntu. Just make a live USB media using [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) from Windows.

[Here](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/guide) is the guide.

While creating USB use persistence.

> What is persistence?
>
> Usually, on a live CD or Live USB key, all modifications are discarded
>   when you reboot.
>
> The persistence allows you to keep your preferences and data even
>   after reboot.
>
> The data are stored in a special file called casper-rw (for Ubuntu)
>   and overlay-USBLABEL-UUID (for Fedora). This is a completely
>   transparent process for the user.
>
> Usually, 300 MB are enough to install some software but you can use
>   more.

The Linux Live USB Creator also has an option to run inside windows using virtual box which it downloads if the option is checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22830/discussion-between-faizan-and-a-b).

Comment: can't upvote because rep but thanks a lot for the answer, I will try to do it as soon as I get home.

Comment: Please read the guide carefully

Comment: I will. Problem might be to have a drive of size and such. With this stuff I always wonder: would "putting" the files into an external drive work? I understand usb=flash and so in this case I guess no, but just in case

Comment: External drive should work with no problem as it acts as a flash device and is plug and play

Comment: The linux live usb creator automatically detects from the iso, the type of OS like ubuntu 14.04 lts 64 bit , etc but sometimes it doesn't detect it correct, so you may have to change the settings and adjust it according to the linux distro required

Comment: Also make sure to use a good & fast USB device (or even external hard disk!), otherwise it can be quite slow.